# how to bind a record field's value to a component? (ie textfield)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In our application, we are getting records' values and setting them on textfields. Then to update a record, we get textfields' values and iterate over them, setting record fields one by one. Is there a way to 'glue' (bind)  a textfield's value and a record's field?

We can't simply use loadRecords on a form because our forms and models does not have a 1:1 similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do out of the box is to use the Ext.form.Basic.getValues and Ext.form.Basic.setValues methods.  These will retrieve and apply an object literal that has keys that map to the name property of fields.

This saves the work of applying and retrieving values individually, but will not automatically update a model's data when a field value changes.